# jquery client doesn't get node js server response

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js

I can send a request to node server, but I can't get the response back. 
Where is the problem?
Help me please!

I have this on server side (node js):

```
const express = require('express')
var myParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express() 
app.use(myParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(myParser.json());

app.listen(3398, () => console.log('ASK app listening on port 3398!'));

var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "admin2",
  password: "password",
  database: "ask_test",
  port: 3306
});

app.post('/selectall', (req, res) =>
    con.query("SELECT * FROM "+req.body.table, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("sending: ");
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result);
    })
);
```

and this on client side:

```
$("#sendticket_button").click(function(){

    $.post("http://151.1.140.232:3398/selectall",
        {table: "test1"},
        function(data){
            alert('done');
            $("#sendticket_button").html(data);
            }
    );

});
```

If I click on button "sendticket_button" I get on server console the expected output with the DB fields

```
ASK app listening on port 3398!
sending:
[ RowDataPacket { id: 2, nome: 'massi', cognome: 'matt', eta: 32 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 3, nome: 'car', cognome: 'petr', eta: 23 } ]
```

but I can't get anything back on my client neither the alert popup. I tried everything.

Thank you

Comment: Try to add .end() after res.send(result);. Maybe the stream won't be finished/closed. -> res.send(result).end();

Comment: You need to convert `result` to string before sending.

Comment: Yes, it was needed. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was a CORS issue.
This, added to the server side, fixes the issue:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    next();
});
```